# Using Javascript to change stylesheets with if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I'm having trouble with my code.. Basically what I want is for when the volume slider is over halfway for it to turn red, and when its under halfway for it to turn green. I have the style sheets created I just don't know how to link it all together. Am I close? Thanks for feedback. (Focus: Last function and the Volume1 input)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Audio Javascript Demo</title>

<link id="green" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Red" href="styleSheets/Red.css">
<link id="red" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Green" href="styleSheets/Green.css">

<script>
var mediaClip; // shortcut for document.getElementById('mediaClip')

function init()
{
// initialise the mediaClip variable  
mediaClip = document.getElementById('mediaClip'); 

// get the length of the audio clip
document.getElementById('clipDuration').innerHTML = 'Length: ' + Math.floor(mediaClip.seekable.end(0) / 60) + ':' + twoDigits(Math.floor(mediaClip.seekable.end(0) % 60));

// updae the displayed data every 300 miliseconds
setInterval(updateDisplayedData,300);
}


function updateDisplayedData()
{
// update the current position
 document.getElementById('currentPosition').innerHTML = 'Current Position: ' + Math.floor(mediaClip.currentTime / 60) + ':' + twoDigits(Math.floor(mediaClip.currentTime % 60)) + "/4:02";

// update the current volume
if(mediaClip.muted)
{
   document.getElementById('currentVolume').innerHTML = 'Volume: MUTED';
}
else
{
  document.getElementById('currentVolume').innerHTML = 'Volume test: ' + Math.floor(mediaClip.currentTime *100  / 243);
}
{

}
}


function playClip()
{
document.getElementById('mediaClip').play();  
}


function pauseMusic()
{
document.getElementById('mediaClip').pause();  
}


function stopClip()
{ 
// There is no stop function.
// Instead, we pause and set the currentTime to 0
document.getElementById('mediaClip').pause();  
document.getElementById('mediaClip').currentTime = 0;
}


function decreaseVolume()
{
// minimum volume is 0  
if(mediaClip.volume > 0)
{
 mediaClip.volume -= 0.01;     
} 
}


function increaseVolume()
{
// maximum volume is 1
if(mediaClip.volume < 1)
{
 mediaClip.volume += 0.01;
}
}


function toggleMute()
{
if(mediaClip.muted)
{
   mediaClip.muted = false;
}
else
{
  mediaClip.muted = true;     
}
}


function toggleControls()
{
if(mediaClip.controls)
{
  mediaClip.controls = false;
}
else
{
  mediaClip.controls = true;     
}
}


function Goto15Secs()
{
mediaClip.currentTime = 15;
}


function twoDigits(number) 
{
if (number < 10) 
{ 
 number = ("0" + number).slice(-2); 
}
return number;
}

function playPause() {
    var mediaClip = document.getElementById("mediaClip");
    if (mediaClip.paused) {
        mediaClip.play();   
    } else {
        mediaClip.pause();
    }
}

function change() {
    var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
    if (button1.value==="Play") button1.value = "Pause";
    else button1.value = "Play";
}

function setVolume() {
    var mediaClip = document.getElementById("mediaClip");
    mediaClip.volume = document.getElementById("volume1").value;

}

function setTime() {
   var mediaClip = document.getElementById("mediaClip");
   mediaClip.currentTime = document.getElementById("time1").value;
}

function backStart() {
    document.getElementById("mediaClip").currentTime = 0;
}

function upVolume() {
    if (mediaClip.volume < 1)
    {
        mediaClip.volume += 0.1;
    }

}

function downVolume() {
    if (mediaClip.volume > 0)
    {
        mediaClip.volume -= 0.1;
    }
}

function gotoChorus() {
    document.getElementById("mediaClip").currentTime = 55; 
}

function changeColor(sheet) {
    if (document.getElementById("volume1").value > 0.5){
      document.getElementById("Red").setAttribute('href', sheet);
  }
  else{
      document.getElementById("Green").setAttribute('href', sheet);
  }
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload = 'init()'>

<audio id = 'mediaClip' controls src = 'take_me_to_church_hozier.mp3'>  
<p>Your browser does not support the 'audio' tag </p>
</audio>

<br>
<button onclick = 'playClip()'>Play</button>
<button onclick = 'pauseMusic()'>Pause</button>
<button onclick = 'stopClip()'>Stop</button>
<br>
<button onclick = 'decreaseVolume()'>Decrease Volume</button>
<button onclick = 'increaseVolume()'>Increase Volume</button>
<button onclick = 'toggleMute()'>Toggle Mute</button>
<br>
<button onclick = 'toggleControls()'>Toggle Controls</button>
 <br>
<button onclick = 'Goto15Secs()'>Goto 15 Seconds</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<input onclick="change();playPause()" type="button" value="Play" id="button1">
<input type="range" onchange="setVolume();changeColor('styleSheets/Green.css')" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='1'/>
<br/>
<button onclick ="backStart()">Reset</button>
<input type="range" onchange="setTime()" id="time1" min="0" max="242" step="2.42" value="0"/>
<br/> 
<button onclick="upVolume()">Volume up 10%</button>
<button onclick="downVolume()">Volume down 10%</button>
<br/>
<button onclick="gotoChorus()">Go to chorus</button>

<div>
<p id='clipDuration'></p>
<p id='currentPosition'></p>
<p id='currentVolume'></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've provided a **lot** of code here for what's a fairly simple question.  Have you tried reducing the problem to the absolute minimum use case?  Try posting as little code as possible while still demonstrating what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to post so much, the problem lies in the last function, and then volume1 input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code, I would:

**1)** Remove (or `<!-- Comment out -->`) which ever CSS stylesheet is NOT default (so leave only the default that will be present when the page loads). Remove the `<link>` element belonging to that stylesheet.

**2)** Rename the remaining `<link>` element's `id` from either `red` or `green` to `styles`

**3)** Update your function as follows:

```
function changeColor() { 
  if (document.getElementById("volume1").value > 0.5){ 
    document.getElementById("styles").setAttribute('href', "styleSheets/Red.css"); 
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("styles").setAttribute('href', "styleSheets/Green.css"); 
  }
}
```

**However...**

This is not the best way to update styles on a page.

A better way would be to still uses your red and green css styles, but instead of having two stylesheets, they can go in the main stylesheet (or maybe a separate `themes` stylesheet). The main thing you'd need to do is update your styles so all rules in the `red` stylesheet begins with `.red`...so for example:

`.red button{...`

`.red input{...`

`.red p{...`

and so on, and you'd do the same for green.

After this, to change the styles, all you'd do is update the class of one of the parent elements on the page (even the `<body>` element though I wouldn't recommend this).

To update a class using JavaScript, you can use:

```
document.getElementById("container").classList.add('red');
document.getElementById("container").classList.remove('green');
```

Comment: @SeamusW - No problem, glad it helped. How did you fix it? Update the function or use the `.red` and `.green` styles?

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS class, not the stylesheet. What I would do is have a "red" CSS class and a "green" one and then do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have a full stylesheet to change one thing but you can use the below function:

```
function changeStyleSheet(styleSheetName){
    document.getElementById("styles").setAttribute("href", styleSheetName);
}
```

You'd give your CSS include an ID of *styles*:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="styles" href="styleSheets/Red.css">`

Then you'd do:

```
changeStyleSheet("styleSheets/Green.css")
```

The `if` statement would be something like:

```
// Random number used, assuming 100 is the maximum value.
if (mySlider == 50) {
    changeStyleSheet("newStyleSheet");
} else {
    changeStyleSheet("newStyleSheet");
}
```

You might want to add an event listener (`onchange`?) to your slider then run the check each time.

Comment: Still can't get it to work.. Please keep in mind I only started javascript a week ago and don't understand a lot of it at all. This is what I have at the moment.

 function changeColor(sheet) {
        document.getElementById("Green").setAttribute('href', sheet);
        document.getElementById("Red").setAttribute('href', sheet);     
        
        if (document.getElementById("volume1").value > 0.5){
          changeStyleSheet("styleSheets/Red.css");
      }
      else{
          changeStyleSheet("styleSheets/Green.css");
      }